# Mixing raw html with template inheritance in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have, what I believe, to be some complex processing of my model data that would be easier to take care of inside my view than inside of an html template.  Thus, I would be returning the raw html inside of HttpResponse.  However, I would still like to get the benefit of template inheritance that render_to_response provides.

Thus, I would like to do something like the following:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<!-- The raw HTML I've somehow 'inserted' -->
{% endblock %}
```

I don't require the use of any other template tags or variable evaluation.  Is this possible in Django?  How do I best go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do such thing is to create a 'generic' template, that would contain exactly what you've posted. Just pass the HTML variable to that template (so, yes, render it normally) and mark it with the [safe template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std%3atemplatefilter-safe).

**EDIT**

Well, sorry, it's not the only way to do this. You could also create a decorator that would accept a HttpResponse and wrap its content around, or you could even create a middleware for this, but the above answer seems to be the most simple one.